# Pause Slider Slideshow on MouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have modified a slider script to mimic ebay's slider on home page.
I am not familiar enough with Javscript to modify the code to allow the slideshow to pause on mouseover. Any help would be appreciated.

Working sample is at http://camoshop.com/test.html

Javascript code:

```
var TINY={};

function T$(i){return document.getElementById(i)}
function T$$(e,p){return p.getElementsByTagName(e)}

TINY.fader=function(){
function fade(n,p){this.n=n; this.init(p)}
fade.prototype.init=function(p){
    var s=T$(p.id), u=this.u=T$$('li',s), l=u.length, i=this.l=this.c=this.z=0;
    if(p.navid&&p.activeclass){this.g=T$$('li',T$(p.navid)); this.s=p.activeclass}
    s.style.overflow='hidden'; this.a=p.auto||0; this.p=p.resume||0;
    for(i;i<l;i++){
        if(u[i].parentNode==s){
            u[i].style.position='absolute'; this.l++; u[i].o=p.visible?100:0;
            u[i].style.opacity=u[i].o/100; u[i].style.filter='alpha(opacity='+u[i].o+')'
        }
    }
    this.pos(p.position||0,this.a?1:0,p.visible)
},
fade.prototype.auto=function(){
    this.u.ai=setInterval(new Function(this.n+'.move(1,1)'),this.a*1000)
},
fade.prototype.move=function(d,a){
    var n=this.c+d, i=d==1?n==this.l?0:n:n<0?this.l-1:n; this.pos(i,a)
},
fade.prototype.pos=function(i,a,v){
    for(j=0;j<this.u.length;j++){if(j!=this.c && j!=i)this.u[j].style.zIndex=0;}
    this.u[this.c].style.zIndex=1;
    var p=this.u[i]; p.style.zIndex=2;
    clearInterval(p.si); clearInterval(this.u.ai); this.u.ai=0; this.c=i;
    if(p.o>=100&&!v){p.o=0; p.style.opacity=0; p.style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)'}
    if(this.g){for(var x=0;x<this.l;x++){this.g[x].className=x==i?this.s:''}}
    p.si=setInterval(new Function(this.n+'.fade('+i+','+a+')'),20)
},
fade.prototype.fade=function(i,a){
    var p=this.u[i];
    if(p.o>=100){
        clearInterval(p.si); if((a||(this.a&&this.p))&&!this.u.ai){this.auto()}
    }else{
        p.o+=5; p.style.opacity=p.o/100; p.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+p.o+')'
    }
};
return{fade:fade}
}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **fade.prototype.move** function to following code

```
fade.prototype.move=function(d,a) {
   if($(this).is(":hover") == false)
      var n=this.c+d, i=d==1?n==this.l?0:n:n<0?this.l-1:n; this.pos(i,a)
}
```

Comment: I replaced the code but now it doesn't progress between slides automatically.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by replacing the second line of your code with:  if ($('#slides').is(':hover') == false)   I think it has something to do with (this) not being the correct variable to check.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion someone posted on TinyFader website:

**For those who asked about a pause button, add the following code to 'tinyfader.js'*

```
fade.prototype.pause=function(){  clearInterval(this.u.ai); };
```

*Replace the ';' that is after the 'fade.prototype.fade =function{...};' function with a ',' then paste this after the ',' so you code looks like...*

```
    //code snippet of tinyfader.js
..., 
fade.prototype.fade=function(i,a){  
var p=this.u[i];  
if(p.o>=100)
{clearInterval(p.si); if((a||(this.a&&this.p))&&!this.u.ai){this.auto()}  
}else{   
p.o+=5; p.style.opacity=p.o/100; p.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+p.o+')'  
} 
},
 fade.prototype.pause=function(){  clearInterval(this.u.ai); };
//end snippet
```

*Once that code is in place you can call the pause function by using 'slideshow.pause()', or '*slidshowname*.pause()'. To play the slide show again just call 'slideshow.auto()'.**

After you do this... try to call the pause function on image hover through jQuery or javascript only...

Try it yourself and deliver us your experience...

Answer (score 0):

I replace **fade.prototype.move** function to following code

```
fade.prototype.move=function(d,a) {      
   if($("#"+$(this)[0]["n"]).is(":hover") == false) { 
      var n=this.c+d, i=d==1?n==this.l?0:n:n<0?this.l-1:n; this.pos(i,a)
   }
},
```